# How to (efficiently) find intersection of two polyhedral cones?

Tags: convex-polygon

I have two polyhedral cones represented by their rays. I am looking to find their intersection, which would also be a polyhedral cone, hopefully efficiently. Does anybody know a way to do that?

Thanks

Deepanshu

Comment: Can you draw a picture for us? I can imagine two polyhedral cones intersecting to give a polyhedron, but for them to intersect and give a polyhedral cone would imply that one is wholly contained inside the other. And what computer language are you using?